# Fourier transformation of solution of differential equation

Tags: fourier-analysis

I'm trying to plot a Fourier transform of solution of differential equation. I have tried with:

```
Plot[Evaluate@
  Abs[FourierTransform[
    Re@Evaluate[
      p[t] /. NDSolve[{p'[s] == 1 + (-1.3 + I*10 + p[s])*p[s], 
         p[0] == 0}, p, {s, 0, 10}, MaxSteps -> 100000]], 
    t, \[Omega]]], {\[Omega], 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All]
```

without success.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The "?" button in the edit box gives tips on formatting, such as how to format code.

Comment: Why not use Fourier? `ff =
   p[t] /. NDSolve[{p'[s] == 1 + (-1.3 + I*10 + p[s])*p[s], 
      p[0] == 0}, p, {s, 0, 10}, MaxSteps -> 100000][[1]]` and `Table[ff, {t, 0, 10, 10/256}] // Fourier // Abs // Rest // Flatten // 
 ListLogPlot[#, PlotRange -> All] &`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the equation analytically :

```
sol[s_] = DSolve[{p'[s] == 1 + (-13/10 + I*10 + p[s])*p[s], p[0] == 0}, p[s], {s}][[1, 1, 2]]
```

Comment: But an analytical Fourier transform for the function seems to be still impossible?

Comment: I think so; also notice the function flattens to a constant for large argument.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting!